# Tracking real time stats for a single page video stream with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, video-streaming

I have a site to stream a live, long-playing video via an iFrame (the content of the iFrame is coming from Azure Media Services and is a live stream).

The site is a simple HTML/JS page which effectively just has an iFrame in it. Users arrive and stay on that one page until the show finished (approx. 45 minutes).

I'm using Google Analytics but because users are not interacting with the page, the real time user count drops off after a few minutes.

I'd like this to be an accurate refection of how many users are watching and how long they actually stay online for.

How do I do this? I've tried this using JavaScript but it has not worked

```
  function ga_heartbeat(){
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'heartbeat',
      eventCategory: 'heartbeat',
      eventAction: 'heartbeat',
      eventLabel: 'heartbeat'
    });
    console.log("Sent heartbeat to GA");
    //repeat every 5 minutes (300000 milliseconds)
    setTimeout(ga_heartbeat, 300000);
  }
  ga_heartbeat();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit a (not affiliated) fan-boy of him, but Simo Ahava explain here a very elegant solution I've also implmented in my past: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-dynamically-loaded-youtube-videos-in-google-tag-manager/

It sends events to Google Analytics and works even with dynamic loaded videos. I hope it helps you as it helped me in the past. As I undestand your question, I think it should be possible for your to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy said, introducing an interactive video events will be a great solution to keep user alive and you can also know the stats like how long user viewed the video.

For Youtube - https://github.com/lunametrics/youtube-google-analytics
For Vimeo - https://www.sanderheilbron.nl/vimeo.ga.js/
Vimeo will be easiest and fastest to implement and for HQ video always.

Sticking to the code alone? the check this example:

```html
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
function myTimer() {

     ga('send', {
      hitType: 'heartbeat',
      eventCategory: 'heartbeat',
      eventAction: 'heartbeat',
      eventLabel: 'heartbeat'
    });  
}
</script>
```